# Loop within a loop - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

On the page that displays a single post, I also wish to display some featured posts.

The featured posts have a meta value assigned to them to differentiate between featured and non featured posts.

The problem is that I wish to display the featured posts half way down my page but the loop starts at the top and doesn't finish until the bottom of the page.

From WP docs:

```
<?php
    // The main query.
    if (have_posts()) {
      while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        the_title();                                                             
        the_content();                                                          
      } # End while loop                                                             
    } else {                                                                      
        // When no posts are found, output this text.                           
        _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' );                         
    }                                                                  
    wp_reset_postdata();                                                        

    /*                                                                          
     * The secondary query. Note that you can use any category name here. In our example,
     * we use "example-category".                                               
    */                                                                        

    $secondary_query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=example-category' );        

      // The second loop. 
    if ($secondary_query->have_posts()) {
      echo '<ul>';
        // While loop to add the list elements.
        while ($secondary_query->have_posts()) {
            $secondary_query->the_post();
            echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
        }
      echo '</ul>';
    }
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

At the end of the first loop, you have to call `wp_reset_postdata()` but in my scenario, there is data that needs to be retrieved further down the page so I can't end it there.

I essentially need to do this but then only the featured posts get rendered and not the post itself.

```
if (have_posts()) {

    while (have_posts()) { 
      the_post();
      the_title();                                                             
      the_content();                                                         

      //Display featured posts half way through
      $secondary_query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=example-category' );
      //end featured post loop
      wp_reset_postdata(); 

      //continue outputting data from first loop 
      the_title();
    } # End while loop.                                                                 

} else {                                                     
    // When no posts are found, output this text.                           
    _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' );                         
}

//finally end inital loop                                                        
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Is it possible to 'pause' the loop to do a different loop then pick it back up again later on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normaly you second code example should work. You don't have to call [`wp_reset_postdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/wp_reset_postdata) to end the main loop, call it only to end the secondary loop.

> Use this function to restore the global $post variable of the main query loop after a secondary query loop using new WP_Query. It restores the $post variable to the current post in the main query.

---

**You can also use** [get_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) for this:

```
$secondary = get_posts( array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 5,        
    'category_name'    => 'example-category',
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',       
    'meta_key'         => 'featured_posts',
    'meta_value'       => 'yes',
    'post_type'        => 'post',       
    'post_status'      => 'publish',        
) );

if ( count( $secondary ) ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $secondary as $entry ) {
        // print_r( $entry ); exit;
        echo '<li>' . $entry->post_title . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```